# make a div animated with a wobble effect

Tags: jquery, css

**Description :**

I have styled a `div` like a calendar. Now whenever I update something in that calendar with a date, it appears on the screen.

Now I am trying to animate the `div` with a wobble effect as follows:

> 1) tilt left
>
> 2) tilt right
>
> 3) tilt left
>
> 4) etc

So far I am unsure if I should be using JQuery/css for this animation.

If anyone could point me in the right direction, I would be most appreciative!

Comment: That sounds nice; where are you stuck? What's your relevant html, and CSS? What have you tried? What went wrong? *How* did it go wrong?

Comment: Pendulums? Wall hangings? See-saws?

Comment: a good way to animate elements is to use jquery and play with the margin values (like += 50px then -=50px etc..) could you provide some jsfiddle of your test so we can help ?

Comment: I haven't used jquery (just pure css) in my answer which may help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fluidblue/dyc96/) of what i think you're looking for:

This doesn't use jscript, only css: (please note. Values can be changed to suit

```
@-webkit-keyframes wiggle
{
    0% {-webkit-transform: rotateZ(2deg);}
    50% {-webkit-transform: rotateZ(-2deg);}
    100% {-webkit-transform: rotateZ(2deg);}
}
@-moz-keyframes wiggle
{
    0% {-moz-transform: rotateZ(2deg);}
    50% {-moz-transform: rotateZ(-2deg);}
    100% {-moz-transform: rotateZ(2deg);}
}
@-o-keyframes wiggle
{
    0% {-o-transform: rotateZ(2deg);}
    50% {-o-transform: rotateZ(-2deg);}
    100% {-o-transform: rotateZ(2deg);}
}
@keyframes wiggle
{
    0% {transform: rotateZ(2deg);}
    50% {transform: rotateZ(-2deg);}
    100% {transform: rotateZ(2deg);}
}

.test {
    background-color: red;

    -webkit-animation: wiggle 0.2s ease infinite;
    -moz-animation: wiggle 0.2s ease infinite;
    -o-animation: wiggle 0.2s ease infinite;
    animation: wiggle 0.2s ease infinite;
}
```

Comment: That is rad.  So to stop it and start it you just remove .test?  That's neat.

Comment: if it helped you, then a great way to say thanks is it accept it as answer ;P

Comment: @Carter yes exactly i figured that out I mean if I use setInterval() and after 2 seconds remove the class it will work like it supposed to or just remove the transition infinity and let the keyframes go to 0.5 seconds... it works both ways :)

Comment: there is also the option to remove/play around with the 'infinite' from the **.test**. setting them instead to an int of 10, say, means it occurs 10 times, then stops completely

Comment: I have one last thing how would you make the degree to which it rotates 1 or 2 less at each rotation like it starts to wiggle at a higher degree and then slowly settles down to zero

Comment: I wouldn't know how to do that with pure css tbh, and not very good at jquery, which i'm pretty sure you would need for that sort of effect :( However, i did find this tutorial after a quick search: http://www.cssreset.com/css3-webkit-animation-shake-links/

Comment: thankyou !! I got what I needed from your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I would handle it by having these somewhere in your CSS.

Then use jquery to add that class from the CSS to your div.

```
div.LeanRight
{
    -ms-transform: rotate(3deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(3deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(3deg); /* Standard syntax */
}

div.LeanLeft
{
    -ms-transform: rotate(-3deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-3deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(-3deg); /* Standard syntax */
}
```